# What's the mechanism of action of Levomepromazine's analgesic effects?

Tags: pharmacology

I have absolutely no idea as to how Levomepromazine elicits its analgesic effects so please do direct me to journal articles and other credible sources with you, the answerer, making a summary of Levomepromazine's mechanism of action in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Drugbank](http://www.drugbank.ca/drugs/DB01403) and the articles cited below, Levomepromazine is an antagonist of several different receptors: These include dopaminergic 2, dopaminergic 4, alpha-1 adrenoceptor, 5HT-2, histamine type 1 and muscarinic-cholinergic receptors.

References:

1. [Evidence for the use of Levomepromazine for symptom control in the
   palliative care setting: a systematic review](http://www.biomedcentral.com/1472-684X/12/2)
2. [Muscarinic cholinergic and histamine H1 receptor binding of
   phenothiazine drug metabolites](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002432058890519X)
3. [Levomepromazine receptor binding profile in human brain—implications
   for treatment—resistant schizophrenia](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1600-0447.1993.tb03391.x/abstract)
4. [Phenothiazine drug metabolites: Dopamine D2 receptor, α1-and
   α2-adrenoceptor binding](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0014299986907934)